# div component in form generation (by schema) not working as expected

Tags: vuejs2, vue-formulate

In a sample project, I placed the "Flexbox Wrapper" code sample [here](https://vueformulate.com/guide/forms/generating-forms/#schemas) (picking from the drop-down list)

The code below is meant to create 2 columns for the children form components of cheese options and toppings:

```
...preceding code...
{
"component": "div",
"class": "flex-wrapper",
"children": [
 ....
```

However it shows both as one column (see image attached.) I have absolutely no other styling asides the header link pointing to the default snow.min.css at by [CDN](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@braid/vue-formulate@2.4.3/dist/snow.min.css).

This is so basic, surprised it's not working as documented. Is there any implicit step I have missed to get this working?

Also not sure why the heading, represented by an 'h3' component in the schema, is appearing as a different font.

[image]

Comment: The example includes styles for `.flex-wrapper`. Are those part of your app?

Comment: Since the example makes no mention neither is there a codepen with it, I assumed all classes needed are part of snow.min.css. How should .flex-wrapper be defined?

Comment: it's literally just `display: flex;`